# Prove $F(n) < 2^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci sequence is deﬁned as
$$F(1) = 1, F(2) = 1, F(n) = F(n−2)+F(n−1) \text{for } n > 2$$

I need to prove
$$F(n) < 2^n$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? The more you can tell us about your thoughts and efforts, the more easily we will be able to tailor and answer to your needs.

Comment: try to apply the inductive assumption but not really get the idea

Comment: Do you know the Fibonacci numbers relate to the golden ratio?

Comment: @xuoimai: What inductive assumption(s) did you make? What about your base case(s)?

Comment: @ Cameron Buie Base cases: (n ≤ 2). F(1) = 1 < 2 = 2^1 and F(2) = 2 < 4 = 2^2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this problem using $\color{red}{\textbf{strong}}$ mathematical induction as you said.

First you have to examine the base case.

Base case $n=1,2$

Clearly $F(1) = 1 < 2^1=2$ and $F(2) = 1 < 2^2=4$

Now you assume that the claim works $\textbf{up to a}$ positive integer $k$. i.e  $$F(k) < 2^{k}$$

Now you want to prove that $F(k+1) < 2^{k+1}$

We already know that $F(k+1) =F (k) + F(k-1)$

By our assumption we know that $F(k) < 2^{k}$ and $F(k-1) < 2^{k-1}$

because we used strong mathematical induction and not just regular induction.

And so we have that $F(k+1) < 2^k + 2^{k-1} < 2^k + 2^k = 2(2^k) =2^{k+1}$
and you are done $\square$

Comment: thank you your answer is very clear Have a good day

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 1):

Use induction.

For $n=0,1$ the statement $F(n) < 2^n$ is true (since $0<1$ and $1<2$).

Assume the statement is true for $n - 1$ and $n$. Then, for $n + 1$:

$F(n + 1) = F(n) + F(n - 1) < 2^n + 2^{n-1} < 2^n + 2^n = 2 \cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1}$

So, the statement is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proof by induction to show this. It is clear that 
$$ \begin{align*} 
F(1) = 1 &< 2 = 2^1 \; , \\
F(2) = 2 &< 4 = 2^2 \; .
\end{align*}$$
Now assume that the proposition is true for $n, n-1 \in \Bbb N$, i.e. $F(n) < 2^n$ and $F(n-1) < 2^{n-1}$. Show that 
$$ F(n+1) < 2^{n+1} $$
by using these assumptions.